# Customize label on x axis in ggplot with xlim

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to customise the labels of my plot while setting the limits of the x axis, but when I include
`scale_x_continuous` it seems that `xlim` does not work

The code is

```
plot_SG <- ggplot(data = session_melted, aes(x=value, y=variable)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 2.8, alpha = .3, col = "black", height = 0)+
  xlim(0,80) + 
  xlab(element_blank()) +
  ylab(element_blank()) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black")) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80), labels = c("0%", "20%", "40%", "60%", "80%")) +
    facet_grid(Session_gender ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free")
```

The issue is that with this code the plot shows value that go beyond 80

[image]

The same happens when I run the same exact code (which includes xlim = 80) with a different dataset which has values up to 60

[image]

What I would like to do is to keep the xlimit at 80 and customise the labels (i.e., instead of 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 - I want them to be 0%, 20%, etc)

Comment: relocate what you are doing with `xlim()` into `scale_x_continuos(limits = ...)`. xlim is just a short cut to scale_x

Comment: `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,80))` could be better adapted to your needs